# Add custom-sized line break before tightemize

Tags: spacing

I would like to add a custom-sized line break between \location and \begin. However, I cannot adjust the linespacing using `\\[1pt]` or `\linebreak`.

```
\runsubsection{Title}
\location{About title}
\begin{tightemize}
  \item first item
\end{tightemize}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `\vspace{}` ?

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks!